# Возможно ли сохранить Map вида Map<Product, Integer> productCount в БД при помощи JPA?

Tags: java, база-данных, jpa, map, many-to-many

У меня есть список Покупка(Sale), которая содержит map вида Map<Product, Integer> productCount, которая отражает приобретенный продукт и его количество.
Могу ли я используя аннотации JPA сохранять данные сущности в БД вида? Какие мне следует применить аннотации, если это возможно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ниже приведены сущности Sale и Product:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sales")
public class Sale {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "card_number")
    private String cardNumber;

    private LocalDateTime created;

    @ManyToMany
    Map<Product, Integer> productCount;
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "product_code")
    private Long productCode;

    private String name;

    private Double price;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "productCount")
    private List<Sale> sales;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, можно ли именно мапу сохранить, но Вы можете сделать третью табличку product_id, sale_id, productCount и когда нужно доставать запросом

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Я уже так сделал, но любопытство берет верх надо мной.